# How to read Azure web site app settings values

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure some key/value pairs for my Azure web application using app settings section on Windows Azure preview portal.

[image]

Now I am trying to read values like below

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyWebApp.DbConnectionString"];

but it returns null values.

Reading app settings from Web.config in my web application works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by `Reading app settings later in my web application works fine.`? Under what conditions you're getting this value as null? Please update your question with these details.

Comment: As a test, does it work if you use a simple name without periods?

Answer (score 45):

I found the solution.

Keep values in web.config as well as in Azure App setting. When you are running/debugging application on your local environment it picks values from web.config.

When you deploy application on Azure it picks values from App setting.

```
//Below code work for both.
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"]
```

Keep key name same in web.config as well as in Azure app setting.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the value that is set in the portal takes precedence over the value in web.config

Comment: On local debug enviornment prioroty is for web.config and on deployment portal priority for Azure app setting.

Comment: guys, please mark this post as answer if it helps you.
Thank you :)

Comment: Just in case anyone else spends ten minutes being a nitwit... remember there is a "Save" button at the top after you edit the strings on Azure. :)

Comment: FYI this no longer works for core 2.2 at least. The value comes up blank. Instead the IConfiguration interface must be used as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-dotnetcore#access-environment-variables

Comment: @A X please try a solution in the below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-linux#access-environment-variables

Answer (score 22):

In Azure, there are a few different ways of retrieving Application Settings and Connection Strings. However, connection strings work a little differently than vanilla application settings.

Application Settings can be retrieved by any method, regardless of whether or not they are present in the `Web.config` file.

Connection Strings can also be retrieved by any method if the string is defined in `Web.config`. However, if the connection string is NOT defined in `Web.config`, then it can only be retrieved using the Environment Variable method.

**Retrieving as Environment Variable**

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_my-setting-key");
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SQLAZURECONNSTR_my-connection-string-key");
```

Note that the keys must be prepended with a string designating their type when using this method.

All Application Settings use the `APPSETTING_` prefix.

Connection Strings have a different prefix depending on the type of database selected when creating the string in the portal:

```
"Sql Databases" --> "SQLAZURECONNSTR_my-connection-string-key"
"SQL Server" --> "SQLCONNSTR_my-connection-string-key"
"MySQL" --> "MYSQLCONNSTR_my-connection-string-key"
"Custom" --> "CUSTOMCONNSTR_my-connection-string-key"
```

For a full overview, see the [Windows Azure Web Sites documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/windows-azure-web-sites-how-application-strings-and-connection-strings-work/).

Comment: You've saved me a lot of nerves :) Thanks!

Comment: Awesome - I love how Microsoft totally fails to document this btw

Comment: @Will How can I differentiate between local and azure environments? How can I read configuration for both?

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SERVICEBUS_CONNECTION")
```

works great!

Comment: Your post gives the impression of just saying "Thanks" for another users contribution. That risks being deleted for not being an answer. But I actually think that you contribute this. Consider rephrasing according to [answer]. Also...

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.